# UIGestureRecognizer iOS

Tags: xcode, uiview, ios8, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add an UIGestureRecognizer to one of my views. It's not receiving any touches. This is what I did:

```
@interface SettingsView()<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *menu;
@end

@implementation FRMSettingsView

- (id)initWithSize:(CGPoint)size {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]) {
        self.menu = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-size.x, 0, size.x, size.y)];
        self.menu.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.menu.UserInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self addSubview:self.menu];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
        recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
        recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        recognizer.delegate = self;
        [self.menu addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    NSLog(@"touch");

    return YES;
}

- (void) SwipeRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"swipe");
}
```

I'm not getting any output. Neither for the touch or the swipe.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I'm happy for every help

Comment: I tried your code, with minor adjustments, and it works. What looks strange to me is the frame of your view, which will be off screen. If it's off screen, how can you touch it? To check that things work, my suggestion is to change the background color (say, red) so that you can see the view, and to change that -size.x to 0, so that the view is on screen. Moreover, it is strange that you have @ interface SettingsView but @ implementation FRMSettingsView. What is a FRMSettingsView?

Comment: It's a menu which is moving in the window with an animation. But maybe there could be a problem... thank you for that hint :) I will check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minor adjustments, your code works. What looks strange to me is the frame of your view, which will be off screen. If it's off screen, how can you touch it? Try to change the background color (say, red) so that you can see the view, and change that -size.x to 0, so that the view is on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Alright! The problem was that I my view was moving from out-of-the-screen inside with in animation. The View is moving but not the GesturRrecognizer. When I set the startPosition of the View to x=0 and y=0 it works.

Thank your for the help Maiaux!

Comment: Very well, then. I'll add my comment as an answer, so that you can accept it, if you don't mind